# Typing in edittext increase its space and decreases the other edittext space

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-layout-weight

I have a linearlayout with two textviews and two editText. The problem is whenever I start writing in any of the editText, the other editText starts being small in space and the focused editText space gets increased as much as typing goes on.

My XML code is:

```
   <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/l5"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtOverAddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:text="Oversease Address: " />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtOverAddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.6"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtReffBy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:text="Reffered By: " />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtReffBy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong. Need help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done few change in your code but I am not sure what is your requirement like
1. do you want to move the text in next line if text exceeded the width of Edittext?
2. Or do you want to scroll the text horizontally if it exceeds the width of Edittext?

I have done both the things in the EditText given. First one move to new line and second will scroll

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/l6"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/l5"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="2dp"
android:weightSum="4"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOverAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="Oversease Address: " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOverAddress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_weight="2.6"
        android:text="Hello I am doing good. Hope you are also doing well"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtReffBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="Reffered By: " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtReffBy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Hello I am doing good. Hope you are also well"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I want to scroll the text horizontally if it exceeds the width of Edittext. Let me apply your answer.

Comment: In this case you will use textMultiLine option with both the EditText. As the same I have used with First EditText. Instead of Multiline you can restrict the number of lines using android:maxLines="1"

Answer (score 1):

If you can set `android:layout_weight` then based on linear layout orientation you can set `android:layout_width="0dp"`

```
   <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/l5"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtOverAddress"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:text="Oversease Address: " />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtOverAddress"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.6"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtReffBy"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:text="Reffered By: " />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtReffBy"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When I did android:layout_width="0dp", Then my textViews text goes vertically.

Comment: You can use android:layout_width="0dp" for EditText only. Try and let us know. I have also posted the answer, please check that one as well

Comment: it is based on your requirement...what you want?
if you want only fix edittext then put width 0dp in only edittext...

Comment: @SummvedJain Thanks. That helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

Create Two Linear Layout with weight 2 within parent Linear layout having weightsum 4. Afterthat you create textview and edittext within each Linear Layout with width 0 dp.

Comment: code given by @Bhupat Bheda is correct just u can add this two line in tetxview   if u dont need text in textview vertically.Or you will have to minimize the edittext weight size and increase textview weight.
android:singleLine="true"
 android:ellipsize="end"

Comment: Thanks, that helped!